# infinite product and convergence criteria 1/n type

Tags: sequences-and-series

If $\prod_{n=1}^{n=\infty}{(-k^{2}/n^{2}   +1 )} $ is known, Is it possible to determine

$\prod_{n=-\infty, n\neq 0}^{n=\infty}{(- i k/n   +1 )^{2}}$ where $k$ is real.

Answer (score 0):

$$\prod_{n\neq 0}\left(1-\frac{ik}{n}\right)^2 = \prod_{n\geq 1}\left(1+\frac{k^2}{n^2}\right)^2=\left(\frac{\sinh(\pi k)}{\pi k}\right)^2 $$
by the Weierstrass product for the (hyperbolic) sine function.